# have spinner update without button click

Tags: android, spinner

So i have made a stat calculator app for a game where the user selects a combination through various spinners and then clicks a button to calculate the resulting stats. So now i want to remove the button entirely and have the resulting stats update automatically when the item in the spinner changes. Here is my spinner listener code:

```
    public class MySpinnerListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {      
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int identifier = arg0.getId();
        String id = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
        id=id.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        Data data= Data.valueOf(id);
        switch (data) {
        //big case switch to find what is clicked an update the variables accordingly..
```

And here is my calculate function

public void Calculate() {

```
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //creates object with all the stats (there are two because the user can compare different combinations) ChangeColor just makes it look nice.

            TotalStats stats1 = new TotalStats(player, car, wheel, glide);
            TotalStats stats2 = new TotalStats(player2, car2, wheel2,
                    glide2);
        ChangeColor leftStats= new ChangeColor(stats1);
        ChangeColor rightStats= new ChangeColor(stats2);

            //outputs the stats
            statsView1.setText(leftStats.builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            statsView2.setText(rightStats.builder,BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        }

    });
```

EDIT: Here is my onCreate method and my initial setup.

```
Spinner character, character1;
Spinner vehicle, vehicle1;
Spinner wheels, wheels1;
Spinner glider, glider1;
Button calculate;
TextView statsView1, statsView2, statsView, title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    statsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statsView);
    statsView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats1);
    statsView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats2);
    title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"New Super Mario Font U.ttf");
    statsView.setTypeface(font);
    statsView1.setTypeface(font);
    statsView2.setTypeface(font);
    title.setTypeface(font);
    InitialSetupUI();
    Calculate();
}

private void InitialSetupUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    character = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.character);
    vehicle = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.vehicle);
    wheels = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wheels);
    glider = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.glider);
    character1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.character2);
    vehicle1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.vehicle2);
    wheels1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wheels2);
    glider1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.glider2);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    ArrayAdapter cadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.character_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter vadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.vehicle_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter wadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.wheels_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter gadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.glider_array, R.layout.spinner_item);

    character.setAdapter(cadapter);
    vehicle.setAdapter(vadapter);
    wheels.setAdapter(wadapter);
    glider.setAdapter(gadapter);

    character1.setAdapter(cadapter);
    vehicle1.setAdapter(vadapter);
    wheels1.setAdapter(wadapter);
    glider1.setAdapter(gadapter);

    vehicle.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());
    character.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());
    wheels.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());
    glider.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());

    vehicle1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());
    character1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());
    wheels1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());
    glider1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerListener());
}
```

Comment: Btw i have tried to move the calculate function inside the spinner listener but it just crashes.

Comment: Can you provide more code please?

Comment: what would you like to see in particular?